# google finance zoom in zoom out graph logic

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I'm looking for logic behind zoom-able graph like google finance. I know there
are off the shelf components that just do that, but I am looking for a basic
example that explains the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever writes things like that basically has two choices.

1. Load a lot of data, and show only a little bit.  When the user changes the zoom, use the data we weren't showing before.  Basically, we load all of the data at page-load time, so the Javascript can use it later.  This is easier to write, but slow; sometimes, you have to load *tons* of data to do it.
2. Load only the data you need.  When the user interacts with the page, make AJAX requests back to the server, to load in the new data that you need.

2a. When you load new data, store everything you've loaded so far, so that you don't need to make more AJAX requests if they return to an older zoom setting.

1 + 2.  Load only the data you need, then show the page.  Then immediately load everything else, but don't show it until/unless they change the zoom settings.

Of these, 2 and 2a are likely the best choices, while #1 is the "get it done quicker" approach.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome (and browsers based on chromium) have developer tools with a network feature that lets you see what happens.

When you load a quote and then change the zoom, you will see a new data request.  For example:

```
https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=AA&x=NYSE&i=1800&p=30d&f=d,c,v,o,h,l&df=cpct&auto=1&ts=1382233772497
```

It makes a new request for each "zoom level", which is necessary because the larger time windows (1 yr, 5 yr) will show data at coarser granularity (1 day, 1 week respectively)